# How to make a window seen in only one viewport?

Tags: 12.10, compiz, workspaces

I have 2 viewports on Ubuntu. If I drag a window in Viewport #1 just a bit to the right (until a bit of its right part is out of the viewport), it starts to appear in Viewport #2.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour? That is, I want to assign each window to a specific viewport, and I don't want them to be seen in any other viewports.

Comment: What is a viewport? Is it a virtual workspace, or a CRT or LCD monitor?

Comment: It's the same as a virtual workspace (i.e. they both exist in one physical screen).